# JSF_Facelets: using <ui:fragment>

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have just starterted using facelets. Please, tell me, what are the advantages of using `<ui:fragment>`. Where the differences between using this tag and just paste code in a necessary place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`<ui:fragment>`, `<ui:component>` and `<ui:composition>` are the facelets equivalent of methods/functions.**

Reusing code via copy/paste bloats your code and makes it unmaintainable, because you end up with dozens of copies of the same code, often with some subtle changes in some of them, and when you discover a bug in that code, you have to find all those dozens of copies and fix it everywhere, and then deal with the bugs when the fix conflicts with some of those subtle changes.

To avoid this, code reuse should happen via methods/functions whenever possible, and differences dealt with via parameters.

Comment: Thank you, for immediate answer! Ok, but what if I have two .xhtml pages. Let the 1 one be a template: there is a block <ui:insert name="ins"> </ui:insert>. The 2 one is pasted in the first one with <ui:composition><ui:define name="ins">SOME INSERTED CONTENT</ui:difine></ui:composition>. There is no <ui:fargmant> tag, but the behaviour would be the same as if it was. So what are the differences?

Comment: This page has examples for the exact differences between the various template-related JSF tags: http://www.packtpub.com/article/facelets-components-in-jsf-1.2 - personally, I find <ui:fragment> and <ui:decorate> a bit strange as well. The most important point may be that <ui:fragment> has a binding attribute, whis is necessary if you need interaction between the UI component and a backing bean.

Answer (score 0):

The advance is the profit of code reuse. If you decide to change the specific code you won't have to go through all places you ve copypasted the code. Instead you will change it in one place.

Comment: Thank you, for immediate answer! Ok, but what if I have two .xhtml pages. Let the 1 one be a template: there is a block <ui:insert name="ins"> </ui:insert>. The 2 one is pasted in the first one with <ui:composition><ui:define name="ins">SOME INSERTED CONTENT</ui:difine></ui:composition>. There is no <ui:fargmant> tag, but the behaviour would be the same as if it was. So what are the differences?